# Javascript and Twitter API

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, api, stream

I made a Twitter Stream that send messages to a discord webhook but dont know how to turn off the stream also sending comments en retweets is there something like a filter for that?

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const Twit = require('twit')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000, // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
  strictSSL: true,
})
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot Running ....');
  var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {
    follow: [process.env.TWITTER_USER_ID]
  })


  stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

    //...
    var url = "https://twitter.com/" + tweet.user.screen_name + "/status/" + tweet.id_str;

    try {
      let channel = client.channels.fetch(process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID).then(channel => {
        channel.send(url)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[filter-level](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters#filter-level) seems like the answer but the documentation doesn't offer too many specifics regarding the valid values. But there are only a few to try. Maybe you could update this post with your findings.